# Is it possible to use MongoDB as database for a html project?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb

Is it possible to use MongoDB as the database for a project where I only use HTML, CSS and vanilla JS? I've tried to google the question, but without luck. Hopefully someone here can give me an answer.

Comment: Do you mean with no server?  Code running in the browser only, and maybe talking to a mongo instance in the cloud somewhere?

Comment: I am completely new to MongoDB, so I have no experience at all. But I want to learn MongoDB, so I was just wondering if it is possible to use it as a database, on the same level as Firebase Firestore for example, in html and/or javascript. Or is it better use another database for HTML projects.

Comment: Well, the mongo instance has to run somewhere.  If you're not running it, then you would need to connect to a remote one.  Yes, you can do that from the browser, but anything running in the browser (connection credentials, for example) can be seen by the user, so it's not secure.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only possible , but even recommended for initial start , since it is the easiest document store available in most cloud services and on almost any platform , also natively supported json format is easy portable later in case you decide to switch , but beside that there is no need of initial schema planning , horizontal scalability and replication mechanisms are build in so as developer you dont need to worry when your data grow in time and need to be highly available ... , I hope this answer your question ;)